# Could not retrieve SSH fingerprint. Make sure that Mac is reachable and remote login is enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I am trying to connect to MAC Build host from visual studio but when i press connect button, above error is shown (same as title of this question).Please spend a few minutes reading following log file and provide me with your precious suggestions to fix it.Thanks

```
    Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin|Information|0|Xamarin - 4.4.0.34-d15-1+3f99c5a
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.AccountManager|Information|0|VS2015 Enterprise
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager|Information|0|No license found for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager|Information|0|Running license sync for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager|Information|0|No license found for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager|Information|0|Running license sync for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager|Information|0|Updated license: iOS VSEnterprise
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager|Information|0|Updated license: Android VSEnterprise
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|Solution loaded: 'PasswordResetModule'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|running fixup on project 'C:\Users\Ali Raza\Desktop\Xamarin Assets\PasswordResetModule\PasswordResetModule\PasswordResetModule.Android\PasswordResetModule.Android.csproj'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|running fixup on project 'C:\Users\Ali Raza\Desktop\Xamarin Assets\PasswordResetModule\PasswordResetModule\PasswordResetModule.iOS\PasswordResetModule.iOS.csproj'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.RemoteServer|Error|0|Could not retrieve fingerprint.
System.OperationCanceledException: Could not retrieve fingerprint. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint, TimeSpan connectTimeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketConnect(String host, Int32 port)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshFingerprintRetriever.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RetrieveFingerprintAsync>b__1() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshFingerprintRetriever.cs:line 47
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshFingerprintRetriever.<RetrieveFingerprintAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshFingerprintRetriever.cs:line 24
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote.FingerprintRetriever.<RetrieveFingerprintAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Remote\FingerprintRetriever.cs:line 20
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: have you googled your error and tried any of the dozens of suggestions for troubleshooting this on your own?

Comment: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond` this line has me thinking it might be a firewall issue. And also what Jason mentioned. There is a ton of help on this out there.

Comment: I have googled it a lot by this error message, "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"   but it gives me links for asp.net and not for xamarin.ios or Xamarin.Mac stuff. I could not find suitable solution that's why posted it here again. I would highly appreciate if you can provide me with some useful link. Thanks :)

Comment: @AliRaza did you figure out the issue? What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I have figured it out. The problem was with virtual machine settings. IT was set to biased connection. I changed it to NAT mode which worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and eventually fixed the issue by rebooting my Mac.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me.

[Pair to Mac for Xamarin.iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#Mac_Setup)

[Connection Troubleshooting for a Xamarin.iOS Build Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting)

*On MacBook* Enable `Remote Login`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The adapter in network I changed it to NAT by bridge adapter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know its sort of late but troubleshooting this issue is very simple with these easy steps

1. Check that your mac agent is not locked and not in sleeping state.
2. Go to your mac agents section.
3. Disconnect and then reconnect to your mac agent.
4. Deploy your app after making sure of Point 1.

In case of any queries revert!